# Uncaught ReferenceError: M is not defined in materialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, materialize

I am trying to use Toast Messages in Materialize and django but I keep getting an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: M is not defined

I have tried typing `Materialize` instead of `M`. I am using Materialise v1.0.0

```
M.toast({html: 'I am a toast!'})
```

Comment: Show full code snippet...

Comment: It sounds like you haven't added the Materialise library to your page. See the 'HTML Setup' section of the docs for more info: https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html

Comment: Both materialize CSS and js were linked successfully

Comment: What is the structure of the project? Can you succesfully use other components? Did you enclose your Toast in a document.ready event? Can you show your code? With just these statements we cannot try to help that much... :)

Comment: Probably another stupid question... Where did you include the js file? In the head section? at the end of the body? Before or after jQuery? As i stated before without informations like these it's difficult to find a solution... ^^

Answer (score 3):

You must import `M` before usage.

just write

```
import M from 'materialize-css'
```

Answer (score 0):

Materialize.js must be included before usage of M.toast